# retaining old array values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to retain array values in a controller.Im intializing an empty array when control enters the controller.Then Im appending values to that array.On calling the controller again how can i retain those old values?

```
visualization.controller('pricing_scenario',['$scope','$http','$location','$routeParams','$timeout','$rootScope','optimalPriceData',function($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams,$timeout,$rootScope,optimalPriceData){

$rootScope.myArr = [];
$rootScope.myArr.push(something);
console.log(+$rootScope.myArr);
```

Each time the controller is called my array is reinitialized.How do i retain my array?

Comment: initialize in the main controller. so when the state changes it will not initialize

Comment: Create a new Service with setter and getter then assign the values to service.

Comment: use $rootscope to store the array values before initializing